# CSS & JS div slider - repeated click

Tags: javascript, css

I have a simple CSS created design. Upon click of an arrow-looking CSS div I have another design slide into the frame from `left: -9999px`. 
I can't seem to figure out how to make that div susceptible to more than one click.

this is what i mean:
Imagine the design looks like an `X`. Upon the click of a div a `Y` slides in from the right. `XY`. When the user clicks the button again I want the `Y` to slide out, and continue the same path to the left. I have the following JS:

```
topleft.addEventListener('click', function(){
  addLeft.classList.replace('out', 'slideLeft')
  addRight.classList.replace('out', 'slideLeft')
})
```

Since i am learning JS I'm looking for a vanilla JS solution, without any frameworks/libraries.
Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
topleft.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (addLeft.classList[1] == 'out'){
        addLeft.classList.replace('out', 'slideLeft')
        addRight.classList.replace('out', 'slideLeft')  
    } else if (addLeft.classList[1] == 'slideLeft') {
        addLeft.classList.replace('slideLeft', 'slideOut')
        addRight.classList.replace('slideLeft', 'slideOut')
        setTimeout(function(){
            addLeft.classList.replace('slideOut', 'out'),
            addRight.classList.replace('slideOut', 'out')
        }, 300)
    }
})
```